# Serial filters in web app

Tags: sql, web-applications, filtering

I am developing a small web app (angularjs/jquery front end, postgresql 9.3 backend) in which I want to present a view of a largish (few million) set of records in a "grid" (read-only).  I have a set of filters based on facets of the data that I would like the user to be able to apply serially; that is, one filter is applied and then the next filter is applied.  The user can choose both the filters and the filter settings.  This ends up being a set of logical AND operations (perhaps requiring SQL joins, as well).

I am interested in what folks do on the backend to improve the user experience.  In particular, I can imagine:

1. Apply filters "dynamically" as a SQL query whenever pagination or additional filtering is applied
2. Create a cache at each level of filtering so that I can update data more quickly

There are clearly other options and I would like to hear what others would do in this situtation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the question is “answerable”, but here’s example of what we’ve done. We have application that does not do filtering but rather allows the use to select which data items that want to see. Like your application, these could include joins to multiple other tables. We have a “driver” table that has the “user” version of the field name, a string for the inner join to the table that contains it, optionally a string for the Where clause if the inner join condition is not sufficient, and the name of the column on the DB.

We build the base query then look at the entries for all the items the user has selected. We add *distinct* inner join clauses form those fields (if three columns are coming from one table, we only want to join it once). We add And clauses to the Where clause encapsulation in parenthesis. And we add the column names to the select list.